# How do determine the equation of motion of slinky?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

I'm trying to analyze the forces exerted to slinky. First, I've divided both ends.

The red vector is the force exerted by slinky itself, and the green vector is gravitational force.

Force exerted in upper side
$\vec{F_u}=kx\cos{\theta_u}\hat{i}+(kx\sin{\theta_u}-mg)\hat{j}$

Force exerted in down side
$\vec{F_d}=(kx\cos{\theta_d}-\mu_sN)\hat{i}+(kx\sin{\theta_d}-mg+N)\hat{j}$

The functions $\theta_u$, $\theta_d$, $kx$ are respect to time variable.

But I can't figure it out how to determine those functions.

Or am I just going wrong way?

Comment: A slinky is a one long beam, with end points contacting the ground and coils clashing. Not en easy problem to deal with in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach ignores the body of the slinky and essentially describes two massive particles coupled by a very light spring, which is not allowed to oscillate or show any of the interesting dynamics a real slinky will exhibit.

Ideally, you should be using some sort of continuum-mechanics approach to this problem, e.g. treating the slinky as a very elastic rod with free ends and subject to gravity, but that can get really complicated.

Alternatively, you will probably get good agreement with the real dynamics if you consider the slinky as a set of massive rings, with linear couplings on their distance, relative angle, and relative orientation (i.e. twists). This is a pretty tall order to do analytically, but should be numerically doable to get pretty dynamics.

Comment: @user24642 Lookup online for multi-mass spring modeling, and maybe it will steer you towards a way of dealing with this.